# Regex Positive Lookbehind alternative in VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

So, [VBScript apparently doesn't support Lookbehind at all.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

I am looking for an alternative valid Regex that I can use with VBScript.

FYI, I will use this in HP UFT, so I've no choice but to use VBScript (If there is no other simplest way, I might have to look into other option like, executing Java (or other language) code from VBS).

**What I am trying to achieve:**
From a given bunch of text, I want to extract certain alpha-numeric string. This string may include `-`, `_`, `.`, `/`, `//`, etc.

Only thing I know is, this string will be followed by a specific word (for example **DIA**) and there will be a space after this string.

Here the VBS code snippet that I can use as an alternative:
This sample code is retrieving the first match only. I can modify it if I won't find other alternative.

```
serviceType = "DIA"

tempTxt = obj.GetROProperty("innertext")

If InStr(1, tempTxt, serviceType, 0) > 0 Then
    iStartPoint = InStr(1, tempTxt, serviceType, 0) + Len(serviceType)
End If

tempTxt = LTrim(Mid(tempTxt, iStartPoint))

iStartPoint = InStr(1, tempTxt, " ", 1)

MsgBox Left(tempTxt, iStartPoint)
```

---

Here is regex that I am using:

```
(?<=DIA\s).*?(?=\s)
```

Here is the [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/1hAQ4j/3) of what I've tried and working successfully.
I just need to find the VBScript alternative.

---

**Update**

Here is the result that I am getting after trying suggested regex:
(The return value looks different because I am using different input text.)

[image]

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Call RegExpMultiSearch(tempTxt, "DIA\s+(\S+)")

Public RegMatchArray

Function RegExpMultiSearch(targetString, ptrn)
    'CREATE THE REGULAR EXPRESSION
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = ptrn
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True    'False
    regEx.Global = True

    'PERFORM THE SEARCH
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(targetString)

    'REPORTING THE MATCHES COLLECTION
    If Matches.Count = 0 Then
        Actual_Res = "NO occurrence of pattern '" & ptrn & "' found in string '" & targetString & "'"
        Print Actual_Res
    Else
        'ITERATE THROUGH THE MATCHES COLLECTION
        For Each Match in Matches
            'ADD TO ARRAY
            ReDim Preserve arrArray(i)
            arrArray(i) = Match.Value
            i = i + 1
        Next
        Actual_Res = UBound(arrArray) - 1 & " occurrence of pattern '" & ptrn & "' found in string '" & targetString & "' successfully"
        Print Actual_Res
        RegMatchArray = arrArray
    End If

    If IsObject(regEx) Then Set regEx = Nothing End If
    If IsObject(Matches) Then Set Matches = Nothing End If
End Function
```

**Final update**

I got the desired result by using the suggested regex. Also I had to use **`SubMatches(0)`** instead of **`Match.Value`**.

Comment: The [correct regex is still the same](https://regex101.com/r/1hAQ4j/4) after the question update, see my answer below.

Comment: Show the code. You did not access the Group1 value (`match.SubMatches.Item(0)` in my snippet).

Comment: `Match.Value` -> `Match.Submatches(0).Value`. You need to get the value of the *capturing group*, not the full match.

Comment: My bad. It's just `Match.Submatches(0)` (or `Match.Submatches.Item(0)`) without the `.Value`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be without `.Value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may re-vamp the regex into a pattern with a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that will let you access just the value you need:

```
DIA\s+(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3hqbxg/1).

Note you do not even need the lookahead since `.*?(?=\s)` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the whitespace. Surely, if you need to check for a whitespace, just append `\s` at the end of the pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `DIA` - a `DIA` substring (prepend with [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) if you need a whole word match)
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace chars.

Here is a VBA test:

```
Sub GetValues()
Dim rExp As Object, allMatches As Object, match As Object
Dim s As String

s = "DIA 8778680044 SVU-RMW ANNISTON SERF1450 COMMERCE BLVD ANNISTONAL DIA DS1IT-15600804-123 SVU-RMW ANNISTON2130 ROBERTS DR ANNISTONAL"

Set rExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With rExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "DIA\s+(\S+)"
End With

Set allMatches = rExp.Execute(s)
For Each match In allMatches
    WScript.Echo match.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next

End Sub
```

Output:

```
8778680044
DS1IT-15600804-123
```

Comment: @ManishChristian: What you *match* is not important, you will get the Group 1 value. You will not get any better regex solution. **See and try the *VBA code*.**

Comment: My solution is still correct. Use it in VBA, not in any regex testers. You asked for a VBA solution, not regex101 solution.

Comment: @ManishChristian Please update your question with the actual code you were using for that. The code Wiktor posted should do exactly what you want, and could easily be converted to VBScript by removing the type definitions and replacing `Debug.Print` with `WScript.Echo`.

Comment: Its working now after making the changes for SubMatches. Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Great. Sorry for mixing up VBA and VBScript.